# Get the count of other collection data from the array based on id Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to get the count of checklists based on department id from departments collections

My collections looks like this:

```
departments : [
{_id: 838383, name: Dump}
{_id: 838384, name: Recycle}
]
checklists: [
{_id: 33333, department_id:838383, name: Tyre},
{_id: 33334, department_id:838383, name: Car body},
{_id: 33335, department_id:838383, name: Wheel},
{_id: 33336, department_id:838383, name: Mirror}
]
```

Now I want to get the list of departments including the count of checklists based on the department id

Here is the response I want:

```
departments : [
    {_id: 838383, name: Dump, checklists_count: 4}
    {_id: 838384, name: Recycle, checklists_count: 0}
    ]
```

What is the best way to do it in mongoose?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try aggregate and use lookup (to find data from another collection)and group to group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$lookup` to achieve this.

```
db.departments.aggregate(
 { "$lookup": {
       "from": "checklists",
       "localField": "_id",
       "foreignField": "department_id",
       "as": "checklists"
    }}
    ,
    {
        "$project":
        {_id:1,"name":1,
            checklists_count:{$size:"$checklists"}
        }
    })
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : 838383,
    "name" : "Dump",
    "checklists_count" : 4
},
{
    "_id" : 838384,
    "name" : "Recycle",
    "checklists_count" : 0
}
```